# the file is not a valid vsix package in vs 2012 express for windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

While adding the sqlite runtime tool to my project  in windows 8 then showing the error 
the file is not a valid vsix package.How to resolve this?any one please tell me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please note that to allow compilation of your project, this one cannot target the “Any CPU” configuration: you need to choose & build specific architecture (x86, x64 or ARM).

Also check [this instruction](http://blog.thomaslebrun.net/2012/10/windows-8-using-sqlite-in-your-windows-store-application/#.UbcmHSX2Zok).